# Call class method or return None

Tags: python, django

I am struggling with database relationships and Django, but have simplified my case drastically in order to get to the point.

I have the following class:

```
class Car(object):
    owner = 'No owner'

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.owner
```

If I do **not** instantiate Car, but set nissan to None and then call get_owner, I get the following error:

```
nissan = None
nissan.get_owner()
AttributeError. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_owner'
```

Is it possible to return None when calling nissan.get_owner() if nissan is None?

The bigger picture: I am writing a Django templatetag that returns some data based on whether database relationships exist. It would be nice to write such code one one line though. In the end, I just want to get the value from get_owner() or get None.

```
nissan.get_owner() or None
```

Is not working here...

Comment: try to `print(type(nissan))` and `print(dir(nissan))` you don't understand what are you doing.

Comment: The whole idea of using classes is that you need to instantiate them _first_.

Comment: Too bad Python has no `Maybe` functor :(

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you should not be able to call methods on `None` objects, I believe you're misunderstanding how object creation works. If you just want to return a `None` value, then don't assign it in the first place. The correct way to declare an unitialized attribute would be:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.owner = None
```

And to use it:

```
nissan = Car()
nissan.owner
=> None
nissan.owner = 'Some Guy'
nissan.owner
=> 'Some Guy'
```

Also note that `get` methods are frowned upon in Python, just access the attribute directly.

Now for the big picture - after having clarified how object creation works, you could test whether the object is not null before using it:

```
nissan.owner if nissan is not None else None
```

Comment: Sorry that was me. Not entirely sure if he's struggling with OO concepts. But your edit resolved any issues I had :)

Answer (score 1):

[`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=builtin%20functions#getattr) should help you.

```
 getattr(nissan, 'owner', None)
```

Also, you don't need `get_owner()` method -- python way is to access the property directly. Find about [`property()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=builtin%20functions#property) to get a direction.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your bigger picture directly, normal python logic operators can help you with this, the and stops at the first False. So this works just fine:

```
nissan and nissan.get_owner() or None
```

Comment: This will, unfortunately, can start failing if `Car` overrides the `__bool__`, or `__len__`, etc. This can be fixed, but is bad design anyway :(

Comment: True, but I wasn't looking at edge cases. I was looking at his 'bigger picture' and trying to help him get further. I did assume he knows what's he doing to some extent ;)

Answer (score 0):

If Nissan is None, it has no method named "get_owner", meaning you can not call this method on a nissan object (or any method for that case). 
you need to make nissan a car, and then decide in which circumstances will the get_owner method return none, and implement that in your code

Comment: Looks like a drive-by downvoter, I was also affected. I hate it when someone does that, with no explanations at all.

Comment: That was me by accident. But also not so sure if your answer makes it any clearer for him to be honest.

Comment: Yes, using logic is horrible! Shame on me. Shhhaaamee! No need to be rude, I said it was by accident. So far each time I try to undo it it ups the timer of it being locked..

Comment: If you want to undo the downvote, Rafi needs to edit the post first